# Using Ajax Redirect not working 404 error display console

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am using routes in my controller as code below the problem is my
ajax call is not redirecting to the controllers action method 
Controller : Custom Action : ContactUs

```
[Route("{id?}/{page?}/{BlogPageId?}")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string id,string page,string BlogPageId)
{
    //some code 
}
```

This is fine but another action is not working

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ContactUs(Contact_Us objContact)
 {

 }
```

Ajax Call

```
$(document).on('click', "#submitCon", function () {      
    var Data = {};
    Data.Full_Name = $("#Full_Name").val();
    Data.Email_id = $("#Email_id").val();
    Data.MobileNumber = $("#MobileNumber").val();
    Data.Company_Name = $("#Company_Name").val();
    Data.Subject = $("#Subject").val();
    Data.Message = $("#Message").val();
    console.log(Data);
    if ((Data.Full_Name == '') || (Data.Email_id == '') || (Data.MobileNumber == '') || (Data.Company_Name == '') || (Data.Subject == '') || (Data.Message == '')) {
        alert("All the fields are mandatory.");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $.post('/Custom/ContactUs', { objContact: Data }, function (data) {
            swal(data[0]);
            $("#Full_Name, #Email_id, #MobileNumber, #Subject,#Message").val('');
        });
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: You want to redirect to ContactUs? Your explanation is a bit hard to understand

Comment: Its just `$.post('/Custom/ContactUs', Data, function (data) {` (but you should use `'@Url.Action("ContactUs", "Custom")'` instead of hard coding the url)

Comment: i got answer  `$.post('/ContactUs', { objContact: Data }, function (data) {}`  **and Controller Action**  `[Route("ContactUs/{objContact?}")]
        [HttpPost]       
        public JsonResult ContactUs(Contact_Us objContact)
        {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**HTML** (index.cshtml)

```
<input type="button" value="Test" id="submit" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','#submit',function () {
        alert();
        var Data = {};
        Data.Full_Name = "Sabya";
        Data.Email_id = "M.sabya";
        Data.MobileNumber = "9090";
        //Data.Company_Name = "Inkswipe";
        //Data.Subject = "Demo";
        //Data.Message = "Test";
        console.log(Data);
        $.post('/Home/Index', Data ,
            function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data["Email_id"]);
                //alert(data[0]);
                //$("#Full_Name, #Email_id, #MobileNumber, #Subject,#Message").val('');
            });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**(Home)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(Contact_Us objContact)
{
    return Json(objContact, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Class**(Contact_Us)

```
public class Contact_Us
{
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
    public string Email_id { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. but this  code is doesn't work with 'routes'